# Managing Regex in java

Tags: java, regex

How we can manage regex in java ?

Yes I did search regex topics but I think it is strange in java.

What I would like to do is

```
My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com>
```

with regex, I would like to get string between < > as xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\<.*?\\>?");
```

Above one didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)<(.*?)>");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("Foo bar <xxx-yyy@aaa.bbb>");
    if ( matcher.matches() ) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group( 2 ));
    }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)

Comment: Strange, works on java 6 on my machine. EDIT: inside jUnit4 test, that is :)

Comment: Really ? what if I do this pattern and matcher in a loop ? does it change any situtation ??

Comment: Now it works, was missing the "matcher.matches()" call that was in my jUnit4 assert, code snippet above updated :)

Comment: Oh now it worked :) thank you so much. I tried other topics but I think there is a bit difference that I couldn't solve.

Comment: The double backslashes in your pattern resolve to an expected '\' in the input which was not what you were after. Feel free to upvote/mark correct my answer if it was helpful :) Take care.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you need to call the find() method on a Matcher object in order to walk through your string. And as Petri Pellinen stated you should check for the right grouping.

Try the following code:

```
String str = "My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com>  My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com> \n " +
    "My team <xxx-yyyy@uucom> My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com> " +
    "My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com> My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group(1));  
}
```

and check the groups fetched.

Results are:

```
xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com
xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com
xxx-yyyy@uucom
xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com
xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com
xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com
```

cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Since it appears you're dealing with standard format email addresses ([RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)) you might want to consider using the [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). It's designed to work with everything within the spec, whereas with regex you might miss some cases. The code for what you want is simple too:

```
String input = "My team <xxx-yyyy@uuuu.com>";
String email = new InternetAddress(input).getAddress();
```